# XCode: ${BUILD_PRODUCTS_DIR} in Scheme Post-Action script is incorrectly translating to debug directory

Tags: xcode

I have a simple script which is running in a XCode scheme under Post-actions which looks like this:

```
cp -fr ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/MyApp.app /tmp/MyApp.app
```

The strange thing is that when I run a command line build via this command line:

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace MyWorkspace -scheme MyScheme -configuration Release clean build
```

The ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR} variable is translating to the debug directory instead of the release directory, and I get this error:

```
cp: /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-afslklkwadvqqggjrlcuycyeyxfv/Build/Products/Debug/MyApp.app: No such file or directory
```

What is even stranger is that in the list of environment variables it is pointing to the correct release location:

```
setenv BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-afslklkwadvqqggjrlcuycyeyxfv/Build/Products/Release
```

This seems like a XCode bug, and the only workaround I can think of is to hardcode the 'Release' directory, which is a really bad idea.

Anyone know what is going on?

Update:

I found a workaround, If I change the Run build configuration in the scheme to 'Release', it fixes the environment variable to point to the release location.

However I don't know why the BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR should be related to the Run configuration, so I'm open to other ways to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. I did a full clean, deleted the **DerivedData** folder, and restarted Xcode - and it disappeared... never to return.

---

Edit: Another idea

How about deleting the debug scheme (or renaming) - then if for some reason it's looking for **debug** it won't be able to find it. Might not solve the problem, but could point to the cause.

Comment: I was really hoping this would fix the issue but it didn't ): Any other ideas?